# Removing an XML line using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I feel my question is going to be really simple, but i've tried it in so many ways and none of them seem to work, i do not know where else to turn.

**What i want to achieve:** I want to remove a single element from an XML file.

**The situation:** I have an XML file that is really simply constructed. It will be more complicated in the future, but for now it looks like this:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <ingredient>First item</ingredient>
    <ingredient>Second item</ingredient>
</list>
```

This list is displayed onto an HTML page. Now when they are generated onto the page, they are given a number, starting with 0, counting up. So the first ingredient has number 0, and the second one has number 1 etc. They have an onclick which sends me to jQuery holding that number. This i've tested and works fine.

Now that's where it goes wrong. I have tried Javascript's $.ajax(), jQuery's $.post() and even making the HTML elements direct forms with a post. None of them seem to work, even if i copy an example directly from somewhere else.

My PhP file to remove the items looks like this:

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Location:index.php');
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('ingredients.xml');

$root = $xmldoc->firstChild; //Take the <list> tag

$toDel = $_POST['itemToDel']; // This is the number received of the relevant item

$root->removeChild(item($toDel));

$xmldoc->save('ingredients.xml');
?>
```

Does anyone have an idea for me? When i tested with a proven working PHP code, it did not implement either, so i have the feeling somewhere between the PHP and Javascript action, it doesn't deliver. As of now, since i removed my previous attempts, this is my javascript right now:

```
function removeItem(item){

var itemToDel = item; // The number of the item to delete.
var removeItem = $('.ingredient')[itemToDel].remove(); // removing the HTML parts

//Remove the matching XML line
}
```

Last minute edit: I can write in my XML file (permissions are ok) and i've used other PHP scripts that does work, so localhost does support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xpath to select the nodes you want to delete and remove them from their respective parent node. DOMXpath::evaluate() allows you to use Xpath expressions to fetch a list of nodes or a scalar value. In this case you want a list with one or no element node.

Select the document element "list" ...

`/list`

... the "ingredient" elements inside it ...

`/list/ingredient`

... reduced to one element by its position ...

`/list/ingredient[3]`

Example source:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <ingredient>First item</ingredient>
    <ingredient>Second item</ingredient>
    <ingredient>Third item</ingredient>
    <ingredient>Fourth item</ingredient>
</list>
XML;

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmldoc);

$toDel = 3;
$expression = '/list/ingredient['.((int)$toDel).']';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $xmldoc->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
    <ingredient>First item</ingredient>
    <ingredient>Second item</ingredient>

    <ingredient>Fourth item</ingredient>
</list>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ThW, but i would like to ask a bit more. In your example, you express the $toDel as 3, and as you know this number is variable. The problem for me is getting this number into PHP from the HTML page. I can get it defined in my HTML page and i can get it into javascript, but the transition to PHP doesn't seem to go as well.

Comment: The example is self contained, so it can be executed without external dependencies (file, user input). You have to adapt it and use `$toDel = $_POST['itemToDel'];` again.

Comment: This answered my question :) Turned out i did make a succesfull call to my PHP file, but with the suggested PHP to delete it, it actually removed it. One last question: How come you use evaluate() in the foreach-bit? Isn't it already correct through the use of '.((int)$toDel).' or am i misunderstanding evaluate()?

Comment: The DOMXpath::evaluate() returns a list of nodes - never a single node, the list can be empty or contain nodes (with the given expression only one). foreach() works with any count of found nodes. So why bother writing source that handles one or none specifically?